# How to get a release form of Qt application built on MSVC without having to install VS

Tags: qt

I have created my own project on Qt and then built a release version of it using windeployqt which works fine of PCs having Visual Studio. When launched on other PCs, the app will ask for missing libraries related to Visual Studio. I tried to download them manually and add them, until there is no library needed left and then it gave me the following error "The application was unable to start (0xc000007b)"...
Can anyone help me on this please

Comment: Please specify which libraries were missing, what did you add etc.

Comment: the missing Libraries are: MSVCP140D.dll, VCRUNTIME140D.dll, urctbased.dll

Comment: These are debug libraries. You should not distribute them along with your application. Use release build instead, if you want to deploy your application on a client computer.

Comment: I tried to use the release build but on windows the executable didn't open a problem that I didn't face on Linux

Comment: The debug runtime is only available on machines that run Visual Studio. It's a violation of the Visual Studio Licence to install the debug runtime on a machine not running VS. You need to build and package the Release configuration. The correct runtime for release is here: [https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)